# Get/set an attribute trough Lightning Event

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning-events

I can't get the attribute trough Lightning Event. By clicking on the button "Get msg" I get `undefined`:

**ceEvent.evt:**

```
    <aura:event type="COMPONENT">
        <aura:attribute name="message" type="String" default="111"/>
    </aura:event>
```

**ceNotifier.cmp:**

```
    <aura:component>
        <aura:attribute name="msg" type="String"/>
        <aura:registerEvent name="cmpEvent" type="c:ceEvent"/>
        <aura:handler name="cmpEvent" event="c:ceEvent" action="{!c.handleComponentEvent}"/>
        <lightning:button label="Get msg" onclick="{!c.getMsg}" />
        <p>{!v.msg}</p>
    </aura:component>
```

**ceNotifierController.js:**

```
    ({ 
        handleComponentEvent : function(cmp, event) {
            var cmpEvent = cmp.getEvent("cmpEvent");
            var message = cmpEvent.getParam("message");
            cmp.set("v.msg", message);
            alert(message);
        },

        getMsg : function(cmp, event) {
            var cmpEvent = cmp.getEvent("cmpEvent");
            var message = cmpEvent.getParam("message");
            alert(message);
        }, 
    })
```

**ceHandler.cmp:**

```
    <aura:component>
        <aura:attribute name="messageFromEvent" type="String"/>
        <aura:handler name="cmpEvent" event="c:ceEvent" action="{!c.handleComponentEvent}"/>
        <aura:registerEvent name="cmpEvent" type="c:ceEvent"/>
        <lightning:button label="Send msg" onclick="{!c.fireComponentEvent}" />
        <c:ceNotifier />
    </aura:component>
```

**ceHandlerController.js:**

```
    ({
        handleComponentEvent : function(cmp, event) {
            var message = event.getParam("message");
            cmp.set("v.messageFromEvent", message);
            alert(message);
        },

        fireComponentEvent : function(cmp, event) {
            var cmpEvent = cmp.getEvent("cmpEvent");
            cmpEvent.setParams({"message" : "Here we go"});
            cmpEvent.fire();
            alert(cmpEvent.getParam("message"));
        }
    })
```

**ceApp.app:**

```
    <aura:application >
        <c:ceHandler/>
    </aura:application>
```

What am I doing wrong? How do i get an attribute?

Comment: When you are clicking the `getMsg` method `event` param is not an event you have created and fired but an `onclick` event and it does not have `message` param. But I don't see that as any kind of an issue in your code since the message should already be displayed in `ceNotified.cmp` because you have handled the event and set `v.msg` value.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I haven't even `msg` on my page. I changed `ceNotifierController.js`. Still get `undefined`.